# Suppressing Blank Mergefields in Word 2010 Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

I'm working on combining two mail merge letters into a Master template that will know which merge letter to populate based on information in a specific column.  I have successfully combined the two letters, but I'm running into an issue with suppressing the blank fields.

For example: Letter 1 has a number of bullet points in the body of the letter populated by different columns in an Excel spreadsheet.  Sometimes these columns are populated, sometimes they aren't.  In Letter 1 when the mail merge is run directly from this document, the template populates correctly: it only shows the bullet points for columns with text in them. The extra bullet points are removed.

However, when I combine Letter 1 and Letter 2 into the Merge Master template, when the Letter 1 data populates (pulling information from the Letter 1 template) it shows all of the blank bullet points that it was suppressing when it was run individually.

Since the Merge Master is pulling the letter templates directly from the original Letter 1 or Letter 2 templates, I really don't think it is anything obvious in my mail merge format.  I'm wondering if this might something related to a weird hidden formatting option somewhere within Word that I am not aware of that is different between the Merge Master and the Letter 1 templates causing things that were hidden to reappear.  Thoughts or suggestions? Has anyone encountered anything like this before?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.